# Selenium WebElement Selection

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Currently, I am doing some Selenium stuff. While doing so, I got stuck in one of the Xpath, which is for Gmail account creation page that is for the birth- month selection option. I have given the Xpath as below which looks good in Firepath as well as in console.

```
.//span[@id='BirthMonth']//div[2]//div//div
```

However, in Java code it's not working; instead, the program is getting hung.

Jave code below is for the above Xpath. Kindly anyone suggest me the right Xpath. Or please let me know if there is anything wrong in my code or Xpath.

```
List<WebElement> gElements = Driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//span[@id='BirthMonth']//div[2]//div//div"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to click div which has display:none property.See code below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='BirthMonth']/div[@title='Birthday']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='BirthMonth']/div[2]/div[1]/div")).click();
```

When first div inside span is clicked then div[2] and all its children are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use below lines will display the list of all birth months:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='BirthMonth']/div")).click();
 List<WebElement> listOfMonths= driver.findElements(By
            .xpath("//div[@class='goog-menu goog-menu-vertical']"));
 System.out.println("Total months: " + listOfMonths.size());
 for (int i = 0; i < listOfMonths.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println("MonthName: " + listOfMonths.get(i).getText());
 }
```

Comment: Hmm.Thanks.. But thing is I am trying to collect all the WebElements related to Birth Months.. means in a List I want to collect all 12 months... Hope you got it ..

Comment: I have posted the code as per your requirement. i hope this will help you.